# Drupal 9 - During installation, Can we programmatically hide some of the installation profiles like (Minimal etc.) and set one default profile?

Tags: installation, module, hook, drupal-8, profile

1. During the installation process want to set `Demo: Umami Food Magazine (Experimental)` as the default value.
2. Want to hide `Minimal`